# android device does not show up under Android Device Chooser

Tags: android, adb

I had 1 nexus 7 and it is working perfectly fine using eclipse android studio. It shows up normally and I can deploy apps on it. (I am using win7 64)

Recently I got 3 more Nexus 7 devices (from same batch, our university bought them at same time). My problem is, when I connect these new devices they are not being detected by ADB.

I have already turned on development option, usb debugging and also allow third party apps from security menu. All 4 devices are updated to android 4.3.

I also tried to do **adb kill-server** and it dint help. The only tablet I can work with that shows up on android device chooser, is the older ( by that i mean the first) tabled that I was working with.

Also under Device Manager, under Portable Devices only the old tabled is showing up. The new ones don't.

Any idea or soloutions?

Comment: Try unplugging the device and changing its usb mode, then plugging it back in.  Doesn't always work, but in some modes adb won't connect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

switch The new tablets into PTP mode (under Settings -> Storage -> USB Computer Connection.) and connect to computer.  Let it install, switch back to USB mode and plug in again.

Comment: That did the trick, but the tablet which was working has the MTP option.

Comment: If the above does not work, try manually installing and updating the USB drivers:

Download the USB driver with the SDK Manager: http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html


Install it using Windows Device Manager: http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#InstallingDriver

Comment: @DavidRust-Smith i'm using lg g3, (with its own drivers installed and updated) and still doesn't work. ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are using the correct android API and SDK version compatible with your device's version in the code. (In the android SDK for eclipse this is in Android Manifest.xml) If the two don't match up, then they won't show up when you try to test it on the device.